# Read a 0 kb file content or file being stream to

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Im trying to monitor a log file, but it seems that the content to the file is not being written to until i for an example click on the file in explorer, then my filewatcher kicks in...

But how can i trigger this effect without having to manually click on the file?

This is what i got so far:

```
        var _monitor = new FileSystemWatcher();
        _monitor.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size;
        _monitor.Filter = "*" + _logFileNameWildCard + "*.*";
        _monitor.Changed += MonitoringFileContentChanged;
        _monitor.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

The problem is that i dont know exactly how this log file is being created since its generated from a game. All I want to do is to read from it, but the watcher isnt being triggered and the filesize is 0kb until I for an example click on the logfile in explorer.

Any help would be much apreciated!

Comment: I did another test running a timer that reads the file each third second, and then i get the data. So my problem seems to be that the filewatcher aint being triggered maybe...

Comment: Maybe it is not being fired for changed event. Did you try subscribing to Created event as well?

Comment: Yes I did and i can tell the watcher is hooked up to the right file, cause if i open it and save it. the wathcer is triggered..

Comment: Although it is hard to believe, [the post](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/) and [this post](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/243272-last-access-timestamp-enable-disable-windows.html) said Last Access attribute is **disabled by default** on Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8, maybe you need to enable it?

Comment: I tried enable it but the result is still the same...